# CodeKit 2 - compiling less with empty lines in code

Tags: css, less, codekit

I'm using Codekit 2.1.8 to compile my LESS files. In my LESS files I have empty lines and I want to have them in compilied CSS file too, but Codekit seems to delete them. I can't find any options in Codekit related to this issue.

Example:

LESS file:

```
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}



a {
    color: red;
}
```

Compilied CSS file with Codekit:

```
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well, no, Less compiler does not preserve formatting (because it literally compiles the source statements and then generates new code from its internal representation). You may apply some specific code formatting after compilation with an additional tools (e.g. [`csscomb`](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js)), but not when it comes to an arbitrary number of lines between rulesets.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'm using CSSComb too, but it will not help me. So unfortunately I have to change my compilied CSS files manually. Unless CSSComb is able to add empty lines after comments somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the default command line or client side you can easily add your own plugins since v2. Less preserves `/**/` comments.

Add in your LESS code for instance `/*3*/` for 3 newlines.

Now write the plugin, call this file `less-plugin-add-newlines.js`:

```
var getCommentsProcessor = require("./comments-processor");

module.exports = {
    install: function(less, pluginManager) {
        var CommentsProcessor = getCommentsProcessor(less);
        pluginManager.addPostProcessor(new CommentsProcessor());
    }
};
```

Than write the `comments-processor.js`:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function( num )
{
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}


module.exports = function(less) {
    function CommentProcessor(options) {
        this.options = options || {};
    };

    CommentProcessor.prototype = {
        process: function (css) {
            var r = new RegExp("(\\/\\*)([0-9]+)(\\*\\/)","g");
            return css.replace(r,function(m1,m2,m3){ return "\n".repeat(m3*1-1); });
        }
    };

    return CommentProcessor;
};
```

**less**

```
p1 {
p:3;
}
/*3*/
p2 {
p:3;
}
/*4*/
p2 {
p:3;
}
```

The preceding will compile into when running `lessc --plugin=less-plugin-add-newlines.js index.less`:

```
p1 {
  p: 3;
}



p2 {
  p: 3;
}




p2 {
  p: 3;
}
```

Comment: Btw., it's nice idea.

Comment: I have one more question... I have installed less in terminal, but it is version 1.7.5. How to upgrade to v2?